# In a function call, why isn't comma a sequence point?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, sequence-points

In the following code

```
int main(){  
    int a=3;  
    printf("%d %d %d",++a,a,a++);
    return 0;
}
```

As specified, From C99 appendix C:,

The following are the sequence points described in 5.1.2.3:

- The call to a function, after the arguments have been evaluated
  (6.5.2.2).
- The end of the first operand of the following operators:    logical
  AND && (6.5.13); logical OR || (6.5.14); conditional ?    (6.5.15);
  comma , (6.5.17)

The order in which the arguments to a function are evaluated are undefined as specified by the C standard.

However, in the function call for printf, we have arguments that are separated by commas which classify as sequence points. So why does this statement correspond to unspecified behavior?

Comment: To be clear: those commas in the `printf` call are *not* sequence points, and they most certainly do not confer any well-definedness onto the obviously-undefined combination of `a++` and `++a`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because the *comma* in the function call is *not* the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) but a *separator*. So it doesn't introduce any sequence point(s).

Comment: When does the comma operator behave as a separator and when does it behave as a sequence point?

Comment: @kevin, e.g. separator `int x[] = {1,2,3}`, `call(1,2,3)`; sequence point: `int x[] = {(1,/*comma op*/ 2), /*separator*/ 3}`, `call((1,/*comma op*/ 2),/*separator*/ 3)`.

Comment: @kevin  The comma doesn't "behave". It is a symbol which *occurs* in a syntax rule. When you use the function call syntax, the commas between the arguments are punctuator tokens which separate. In a comma expression, the comma denotes an operator. So it depends on which syntax rule is obeyed by the thing that you're writing.

Comment: In other words, the language spec allows *comma* to have different behaviours. You can also ask ((and many similar questions) why  the *multiplication operator* `*` is used to dereference a pointer (e.g.`*p=5;` :)